# How to calculate the redundancy of a language

Tags: cryptography, cryptanalysis

I'm trying to calculating the unicity distance for a cipher applied to a language I wrote and I'm having trouble understanding the concept of redundancy in a language.

From [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=pTexCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=redundancy+of+english+security&source=bl&ots=7YVufB-RLQ&sig=ACfU3U3aSSdraR5lvt0s80cRP6S8H4Epvw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSxpXrhbzoAhXlGTQIHYlSCXQQ6AEwC3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=redundancy%20of%20english%20security&f=false)

> The redundancy of a language severely reduces the amount of information conveyed with each character and the rate of a language is defined as the average number of bits of information contained in each character of a message, i.e. H(X)/N where N is the number of characters in the message.

You need to generate a frequency table for a language to calculate H(X) but an accurate frequency table requires a long message. Won't this cause all redundancies to tend towards 0 since N can be arbitrarily long? How exactly is the redundancy for English, 1 to 1.5 given by this book, calculated? What value of N do they use?

Comment: please do not cross-post on StackExchange